# A phrase for 'a free, informal space for learning'

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions, phrase-requests, slang

What could be a short phrase for 'a free and informal space for learning?'

Comment: Could you expand your description a bit. What do you mean by *informal*?

Comment: but exactly informal but I dont want to use any uncommon words

Comment: Can you describe the space more. Who goes there? Is there a teacher? A guide? Does it have resources? Books? Internet? Etc.

Comment: How about the **internet**?

Comment: *meta*: What is unclear here?

Answer (score 3):

A 'study' can be a physical place, usually a room for solitary work however.

Depending on degree of formality, a forum can be considered a place for conversation based development of ideas, usually goal-oriented.

Technically, a public library falls well into this category as being both free and informal with a large volume of educational texts available and with many libraries have local events and workshops for people to learn more directly from others.

Incidentally, a 'workshop' can refer to a type of event that is based around group learning, critique, and improvement by peers, and can be free.

Comment: Also, I can't comment on questions yet, but I interpreted the question as meaning 'free from charge' more than 'freeform'

Answer (score 1):

How about including the words Lounge or Salon?

Comment: I mean to intend a learning space not a general space. This doesn't anyhow restrict it to learning space

Comment: I understand, my point was to add a casual place like lounge or salon to a word Like Learning or Study... then you'd have Learning Lounge or Study Salon or some variation.

Answer (score 1):

**"Study Hall"** describes a physical space and its intent as well as being an idiomatic term of a classroom in most high schools where a student could go for a period of studying between other scheduled classes.

Answer (score 1):

**Study circle**

[WP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Study_circle):

> A study circle is a **small group of people who meet multiple times to discuss** an issue. Study circles may be formed to discuss anything from politics to religion to hobbies. They are differentiated from clubs by their focus on exploring an issue or topic rather than on activities or socializing. When they emerged in the early twentieth century they were based on **a democratic approach to self-education** and were often linked to social movements concerned with temperance or working class emancipation. [emphasis added]

[Cecile Andrews](http://www.context.org/iclib/ic33/andrews/):

> *Study Circles: Schools For Life
>
>   Cooperative learning, democratic participation, respect for individual views, and learning from the collective wisdom of the group*

[Copian](http://en.copian.ca/library/learning/study/scguide.htm):

> Study circles are an effective way of facilitating inexpensive educational opportunities where the students take responsibility for their own learning. Learning in the study circle setting is not passive and requires a commitment to active thinking and learning.

See also:
[Aliona Velichko](http://web.archive.org/web/20070928064116/http://aha.adukatar.net/storage/users/2/2/images/16/Digest_pages_23-25.pdf)
*Welcome to the world of study circles* [pdf ~63kB]

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the context, but it sounds as if a coined word might fit your requirements.

I am thinking about: **edupub** (or *edu-pub*)

The *edu* is from *education*, and *pub* can be interpreted as either *public* (for the sense "free"), or *pub* (for the sense of "place").

Hope this helps.